# Computer wont turn on immediately

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, switch

Having an issue with my stack, I'll try to describe it as best I can. Was hoping for some advice from you kind people.

I turn off my computer normally every time I shut it down, no programs running no nothing. After it has completely turned off I switch the power supply unit in my computer off at the back using the switch on the unit, and then switch the multi-block of at the wall (it has all my other components on it for my computer i.e monitor,speakers).

I come back to it the next day switch it all back on in reverse order, but the power button does nothing and on-board LED on the motherboard isn't on. After a while the LED starts to sporadically flash. Then after a few more minuets the LED will the stay lit and my computer will turn on with no problem or issues. This can take anywhere from 1 - 15 mins to turn on.

All the components attached to the multi block work normally before and after the computer powers up and I have replaced the power cord with a known working one.

What should my next steps be??

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Replace your power supply.  It is most likely faulty and on its way out.  (If you are good with a soldering Iron, you might want to investigate it by opening it up, looking at the caps and replacing any which are bulging)